# Not getting the record count each 6 hour interval using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I need to fetch result count at each 6 hr time interval by matching user input value using MongoDB. My query is:

```
db.user.aggregate([
      { $match : { caseState : state, caseStatus:status } },
       { $group: {
    _id: {
      year: { $year: "$createdDate" },
      dayOfYear: { $dayOfYear: "$createdDate" },
      hour: { $hour: "$createdDate" },
      interval: {
        $subtract: [ 
          { $minute: "$createdDate" },
          { $mod: [{ $minute: "$createdDate"}, 60*6] }
        ]
      }
    }},
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
    ])
    .toArray((err, docs)=>{
        console.log('docs',docs);

    })
```

Here in console I am getting the result undefined. My requirement is by matching the user input value of `state and status` the record count will be fetch like below.

```
0-6           2
12-18         1
...............
```

As per my code I am getting the result `undefined`.

Comment: Can you give us sample data of your collection, Also can you make sure you handle if(err) console.log(err) first & then console.log('docs',docs); As it says 'undefined' rather than empty seems like some error with the aggregation pipeline !!